# Координаты проекции точки на окружности

Tags: javascript, математика, геометрия, тригонометрия

уже совсем запутался в тригонометрических формулах, так как везде пишут по-разному, суть такова, есть окружность и в ней точка, которая не должна заходить за пределы этой окружности, но координаты этой точки могут естественно быть больше.
Сейчас это работает так:

```
const offset = { x: 25, y: 24 };
const radius = 20;

if (Math.pow(offset.x, 2) + Math.pow(offset.y, 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2)) {
    coordinates = offset;
}
```

Но тут проблема в том, что если условие не проходит, то точка естественно замирает на месте, а должна двигаться и дальше, просто в пределах окружности, поэтому как я понял, мне нужно находить проекцию от координаты, чтобы отображать ее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Красным отмечена точка, которая должна отображаться, а за пределами - текущая точка)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cчитаем расстояние до точки, если оно больше радиуса - корректируем компоненты.

```
const offset = { x: 25, y: 24 };
const radius = 20;

len = Math.hypot(offset.x, offset.y) ;
if (len > radius) {
    coordinates.x = offset.x * radius / len;
    coordinates.y = offset.y * radius / len;
}
else {
    coordinates = offset;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, от части работает, точка крутится вокруг края окружности, но если координаты точки меньше радиуса, то она должна быть внутри окружности (по типу радара), поэтому в коде и стоит условие, что если координаты больше, то оставляем в пределах окружности)

Comment: OK,  тогда `if (len > radius)`. А в коде у вас обратное условие

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, тут такое условие стояло, чтобы наоборот заблокировать дальнейшее изменение положения, тоесть код теперь вот такой
`if (len > radius) {
coordinates = { x: (offset.x * radius) / len, y: (offset.y * radius) / len };
} else { coordinates = offset }`

Comment: OK, понятно, я во втором случае не скопировал.